# I need a little more explanation with Creation of Process in OS

Tags: process, operating-system

I was going through the Process States. The first state was "Creating Process". What do we mean by creating the process? Is it the completion the program and saving into the hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

The state 'Creating Process' is what you refer to before it goes into a ready state, that is ready to be scheduled by the OS. The process creation state refers to the initial setup of the essentials of a process. In UNIX, at system boot, the first user level process is created called 'init' which is the parent of all the other processes.

UNIX `fork()` is used to create a new process. During this process creation, the `fork()` will create a new address space for the child process, a process id (pid) will be assigned, all the mapping of the parent process will be copied into the child's address space and the new program will  be loaded in to the child process's address space. This is what happens in 'Process Creation' and once `fork()` it is followed by a `exec()` call which will allow the child to run its own program.